# Seeking Correct 2x2 Matrix Representation for CL(1,1) in Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I'm working with the Clifford algebra $ \text{CL}(1,1) $ and attempting to find an appropriate $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix representation. This algebra corresponds to a space with the metric signature $ (1, -1) $ or $ (-1, 1) $, and its generators should satisfy specific relations:

- $ (\gamma^0)^2 = I $ (the identity matrix)
- $ (\gamma^1)^2 = -I $ (the negative of the identity matrix)
- $ \{\gamma^0, \gamma^1\} = 0 $ (they anticommute)

I've explored some representations, like:

- $ \gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $
- $ \gamma^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $

However, in this representation, the pseudoscalar $ i = \gamma^0\gamma^1 $ doesn't square to -1 as expected. Could someone provide the correct $ 2 \times 2 $ matrix representation for $ \text{CL}(1,1) $ that adheres to these algebraic requirements?

Comment: The pseudoscalar should square to $+1$, not $-1$ (this follows from the defining relations that you have written down). So your matrix representation is correct.

Comment: @HansLundmark in CL(1,1), the pseudoscalar squares to +1 ?!?

Comment: Yes. If $e^2=1$ and $f^2=-1$ and $ef+fe=0$, then $(ef)^2=efef=-effe=+e^2=1$.